# Referencing Dynamic content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I use the following code through out my application to create hyper links that load pages into a DIV element

```
$(".OpenInContent").click(function () {

linkObj = $(this);
var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
$('#ActiveContent').empty();
$('#ActiveContent').load(viewUrl);
return false;

});
```

So for example lets say i have a page called "main.html" with the following html. (the above javascript is at the bottom of this page)

```
<a class="OpenInContent" href="test.html"> 
<div id="ActiveContent" style="display: block;"></div>
```

This loads the contents of test.html into the DIV with ID ActiveContent.

But what if the content of test.html also contained a hyper link with the "OpenInContent" class?

The only way i can get this to work is to put the same Javascript on the bottom of the test.html page.

What is the best method to accomplish this?  I am assuming loading the same javascript code twice is not it!

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

Using delegation with `.on()` is the way to target dynamic elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.OpenInContent', function () {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Remove the opening parenthesis before `function`.